# DirectX moving my GUI

Tags: c++, math, directx

I'm creating a overlay for a friend of mine, I wanted to implement so I can move my box dynamically when I'm holding left mouse button.
This is my current method:

```
    if (mouse.isClicked() && (cursor.x >= mainGUIBox.x) && (cursor.x < (mainGUIBox.x+mainGUIBox.w)) &&
                             (cursor.y >= mainGUIBox.y) && (cursor.y < (mainGUIBox.y+40)))
    {
        DrawString("CLICKED BOX", 500, 500, 255, 0, 0, ppFont);
        float xxxx = cursor.x-(mainGUIBox.x+cursor.x);
        float yyyy = cursor.y-(mainGUIBox.y+cursor.y);
        mainGUIBox.x = xxxx;
        mainGUIBox.y = yyyy;

    } // Move MainGUI
```

But this method doesnt work, it shoots my box outside of my screen as soon as I click the box to move it :P

I'm quite bad at math, and I cant really find a nice equation to find this out dynamically and allign it after my mouse.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

```
cursor.x - (mainGUIBox.x + cursor.x)
```

is the same as

```
cursor.x - mainGUIBox.x - cursor.x
```

wich is

```
- mainGUIBox.x
```

When you click the box, its coordinates become negatives, wich is probably outside of your screen.